# Profile2 taxanomy and views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

i have a problem considering drupal 7 and views.
i have a taxonomy view the lists al the terms:
http://conversal.w0p.be/feesten

Now i have used profile2 for tagging my profiles an made a second view that listens to an argument /feesten/%

But now if i want to get all the http://conversal.w0p.be/feesten/evenementen 
profiles i et the page that gives the detail of that term and not the profiles.
Ive googled a lot and can't find any good answer related to this :s

THNX in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Have it working now :)
made 2views 1taxonomy view and 1profile view and renamed the taxonomypath to something else.
and rewrite the taxonomy-name url in the taxonomy view